# Error: React infinite loop. Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setstate

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this error when I make changes the input field. I am not very good with react, still learning. If anyone can help me figure this out, that would be appreciated.

```
const config = getConfig();
class MyModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            branch: '',
            loader: false,
            saveActionLoader: false,
            currentDoc: 1,
            formData: '',
            viewEditDetails: true,
            branchValidation: false,
            comment: '',
            coverpage_type: '',
            physicianData_fax: {},
            coverpage_validation: false,
            physician_validation: false,
            view_check: 0,
            faxNumberVerify: false,
            phoneNumberVerify: false,
            npiVerify: false,
            emailVerify: false,
            physicianLink: false,
            editPhysician: false,
            currentLookup_Rec: 'Physician',
            recipientData: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        
       
        let fieldDataObj = GetFieldData({ configData: this.props.configData });
        GetStore(fieldDataObj);
    }

 

    saveAction = async () => {
        // Implement your save action logic here
    };

    clearAll = () => {
        // Implement your clearAll logic here
    };

    handleCloseAction = () => {
        const { updateState } = this.props;
       
    };

   
    updateState = (state) => {
        if (typeof this.props.updateState === 'function') {
            this.props.updateState(state);
        }
    };
    render() {
        const { openFaxNow, configData, branchOptionArray } = this.props;
        const {
            branch,
            loader,
            viewEditDetails,
            branchValidation,
            comment,
            coverpage_type,
            recipientData,
            currentLookup_Rec,
            physicianData_fax,
            coverpage_validation,
            physician_validation,
            view_check,
            faxNumberVerify,
            phoneNumberVerify,
            npiVerify,
            emailVerify,
            physicianLink,
            editPhysician
        } = this.state;

        return (
            <Modal
                show={this.props.openFaxNow}
                onHide={this.clearAll}
                animation={false}
                size='lg'
                className='notes-popup upload_popup'
                aria-labelledby='contained-modal-title-vcenter'
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Body>
                    {viewEditDetails === false ? (
                        <div style={{ textAlign: 'center', marginTop: '20px' }}>
                            <Loader
                                type='Oval'
                                color='#007dbc'
                                height={40}
                                width={40}
                            />
                        </div>
                    ) : null}
                       <div className='mb-2' id='upload-form'>
                      <hr />
                      
                        <DetailSection
                                open_edit_details={true}
                                isLocked={false}
                                isDetailBigView={false}
                                selectedDocId={''}
                                updateState={(state) => {
                                    this.setState({ ...state }, () => {
                                        this.updateState(state);
                                    });
                                }}
                                isUploadPage={true}
                                calingFrom='upload'
                                submitEditPatient={() => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        submit_edit_patient: true,
                                    });
                                }}

                                coverpage_commentFunction={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        submit_edit_patient: true,
                                    });
                                }}
                               
                                coverpage_typeFunction={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        coverpage_type: e.value,
                                    });
                                }}
                                PhsicianData_Function={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        physicianData_fax: e.value,
                                    });
                                }}
                                PhsicianLink_Function={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        physicianLink: e.value,
                                    });
                                }}
                                Recipient_Data={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        recipientData: e.value,
                                    });
                                }}
                                setView_check={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        submit_edit_patient: true,
                                    });
                                }}
                                setCurrentLookup_Rec={(e) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        currentLookup_Rec: e.value,
                                    });
                                }}
                                
                                checkingEdit_Physician={(value) => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        physicianLink: value,
                                    });
                                }}
                                
                                
                                
                              
                                 
                            />

                        </div>
                           
                    </div>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer className='d-block delete_btn'>
                    <div className='d-flex footer-btn align-items-stretch justify-content-between'>
                        <div className='d-flex'>
                            <button
                                variant='secondary'
                                onClick={this.handleCloseAction}
                                title='Cancel'
                            >
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='d-flex'>
                            <button
                                variant='secondary'
                                onClick={this.clearAll}
                                title='Clear ALL'
                            >
                                Clear ALL
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className='d-flex'>
                            <button
                                className='fax-outer'
                                onClick={this.saveAction} 
                                title='Submit'
                            >
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
 
const mapDispatchToProps = {
   
};
const mapStateToProps = (state,ownProps) => {
    const itemState = ownProps;
    return {
        ddl: state.persistDDL.DDL,
        configData: state.configReducerPersist.configData,
        rowData: state.inbox.rowData,
        count: state.persist.count,
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyModal);
```

[image]

Comment: You're setting the `physicianLink` at two places. Is that necessary? Also, it depends on how you are using these two update functions inside the `DetailSection` component. A little color on that would help debug further.

Comment: @Bmsbharadwaj: Can you please share your email with me if you don't mind. I don't want to put all the DetailSection on stackoverflow